# why is my <h1><small></small></h1> not lineing up

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

So I have been trying to do this for about an hour now and I have exhausted to my knowledge how to get this to work. Am I doing something small wrong that I cannot see?

```css
.center {
  width: 50%;
  margin: 0px auto;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="center">
  <ul class="inline">
    <li>
      <h1>8$:</h1>
    </li>
    <li>
      <h1><small> 512mb</small></h1>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: What bootstrap? Twitter bootstrap? Is those `center` and `inline` classes defined by you? if yes, please show their css definitions.

Comment: Added, center is mine inline is part of bootstrap(twitter)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you want it this way?

Screenshot

[image]

CSS Code

```
h1 small {vertical-align: middle;}
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/praveenscience/jcyam/

Answer (score 2):

Using both the h1 and small tags seems counterintuitive. I would use one or the other.

An `<H1>` tag is for a heading and/or naming a section of content.

A `<small>` tag is typically used for info in the footer such as contact info.

I don't think they should be embedded within each other in any case. Try one or the other, but not both.

Answer (score 1):

A couple of things to note here.

1. You should only have one `h1` tag on each page.
2. You can always change the `class` of an `h1` tag if you do not want it to be the size that you have set for a regular `h1` tag.

For example, you can do this: `<h1 class="smallClass">512mb</h1>`

Comment: Rule #1 is pretty arbitrary.

Comment: Rule #1 is not true for HTML5.

Comment: True, it's also common practice amongst most developers. :)